# canvas.toDataUrl("image/jpeg") not supported in IE10?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to generate a jpeg image from a canvas element by setting an image src to:

```
myCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.7);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kor82mg5/)

It's working fine in Chrome and Firefox but in IE (10) the output is a png instead of jpeg.

Is `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")` not supported in IE(10)?

Comment: IE10/11 supports JPEG by intention but toDataURL() seem to be broken in IE (or a common component since the problem is also in IE11) at the moment. You could consider filing a bug with Microsoft.